# HackerRank problem PlusMinus using for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I need very specific answer to this particular HackerRank problem : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/plus-minus/problem.

Why this code is passing all the test-cases ?

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
let positives = 0
    let negatives = 0
    let zeros = 0
    const length=arr.length

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
        if (arr[i] > 0) {
            positives++
        } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
            negatives++
        } else {
            zeros ++
        }
    }

    const positiveRatio = Number(positives / length).toFixed(6)
    const negativeRatio = Number(negatives / length).toFixed(6)
    const zeroRatio = Number(zeros / length).toFixed(6)

    console.log(positiveRatio)
    console.log(negativeRatio)
    console.log(zeroRatio)
}
```

And why this code is not passing any test-case ? 
(I have edited my code: sorry for earlier wrong code) This code also does not works.

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
var l = arr.length;
var positiveCounter = 0;
var negativeCounter = 0; 
var zeroCounter = 0;

for(var i=0; i<=l; i++) {
    if (arr[i]>0) { 
        positiveCounter+=1;
    } else if (arr[i]<0) { 
        negativeCounter+=1; 
    } else { 
        zeroCounter+=1; 
    }
}

console.log (
(positiveCounter/l).toFixed(6)+ '\n' +(negativeCounter/l).toFixed(6)+ '\n' +(zeroCounter/l).toFixed(6) );
 }
```

I don't want alternative ways to solve this. I just want to know why the first code works and the second code doesnt ???

Comment: The second output is not the same as the first output. Whereas the first output prints 3 separate values to console, the second one prints 1 value with linebreaks inside.

Comment: in the second example, each counter is divided by the array length twice e.g. `p = positiveCounter / l` and then `console.log( (p / l).toFixed(6))`

Answer (score 3):

These 2 codes are different, you are dividing the numbers by the length twice

- First in the assignment to a variable (`var p= ...`)
- Second when doing the console.log (`(p/l).toFixed(6)`)

Also, like mentionned by @DhananjaiPai, they have multiple `console.log` and you only have one with breaking characters which can be differently interpreted by OS (`\r\n` or `\n` )

You also have a something wrong in your loop, I will let you find that one but remember that an array begin from the index 0, if the array has 3 elements, that will be `[0, 1, 2]`

Comment: I have edited my code: sorry for earlier wrong code. 
This code also does not works. My question remains the same.

Comment: How about 3 `console.log` instead of one?

Comment: Nope. Putting 3 ```console.logs``` also does not work !

Comment: Just added a comment for you in my post @SyedSherAliHussain